# Received SMS not displaying completely in TextView

Tags: android, android-intent, textview, sms, broadcastreceiver

I've been trying to create a simple application that will send SMSes to an information gateway and will also be able to display the SMS received about the requested information within the app.

I've got the first part right, but there is something missing in the second half, that is, receiving the SMS. I'm successfully been able to get access to the TextView onto another class using mThis, but I'm not able to get the complete message, only a small snippet of it.

Here are a few screenshots to make you understand:

[image: Here, I'm doing a Wikipedia Search for MJ, and once that is done, a message of the text-version of the Wiki Article is sent to me.]

*Here, I'm doing a Wikipedia Search for MJ, and once that is done, a message of the text-version of the Wiki Article is sent to me.*

[image: This is the message I got from the gateway, a short and sweet article about my favorite artist.]

*This is the message I got from the gateway, a short and sweet article about my favorite artist.*

[image: But this is what I get... a shortened and sometimes incomplete version of the whole message, which doesn't make sense for some searches.]

*But this is what I get... a shortened and sometimes incomplete version of the whole message, which doesn't make sense for some searches.*

This is the code I have on **ReceiveMessage.java**, the main class file that allows me to receive and display the SMSes.

```
package com.phoenix.omnisurf;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class ReceiveMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            }
            if (messages.length > -1) {
                Surf.mThis.messageContainer.setText(messages[0].getDisplayMessageBody());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is what my **activity_surf.xml** contains, the main layout that has the messageContainer TextView that displays the received message. (*just a snippet*)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/messageContainer"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSurf" />
```

Please do help me in displaying the complete message on the app, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is just a guess, but I bet whats happening is the message is getting split up because its longer than 140 characters, the standard length of a text message. You need to get the second half.

Comment: @bwoogie You are right, and I realized this right after I posted this question. I have now added an answer to my own question that worked, please review it and let me know if that's the proper way to execute it, or if there was any other streamlined way to process multiple message blocks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the Original Poster's own Answer, this is one less `for` loop.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class ReceiveMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
    private String messageBody = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {

                messageBody = "";

                Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messageBody += SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]).getDisplayMessageBody();
                }

                Surf.mThis.messageContainer.setText(messageBody);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't realize at the time was, that SMSes are sent in blocks (in PDU) and what I was doing was reading just the first array *messages[0]*'s message body.

All I had to do was implement the same for loop to catch all the messages and use it to store/append all the messages into one string variable *messageBody*.

I also had to clear out the *messageBody* every time a new SMS was received so that it doesn't keep displaying the old one.

**This is the new and improved code:**

```
package com.phoenix.omnisurf;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class ReceiveMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
private String messageBody = "";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {

            messageBody = "";

            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            }

            if (messages.length > -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messageBody += (messages[i].getDisplayMessageBody());
                }
            }

            Surf.mThis.messageContainer.setText(messageBody);
        }
    }
}
}
```